# Realizar una validacion a la base de datos react mongodb

Tags: html, nodejs, reactjs, mongodb, express

Estoy tratando de crear un usuario nuevo, pero no quiero que haya duplicados.
En el evento `onsubmit` quiero que vea si en la base de datos hay un dato igual, ya sea email o usuario y si lo hay que me de un mensaje diciendo "email actualmente registrado" o "nombre de usuario existente".

```
onSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();

       await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/api/users', {params: {username: this.state.username}})
       .then(response=>{
           alert('Username already exist.')
       })

       await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/api/users', {params: {useremail: this.state.useremail}})
       .then(response=>{
           alert('Email already exist.')
       })
   
  
        await axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/users', {
        useremail: this.state.useremail,
        username: this.state.username,
        userpassword: this.state.userpassword

     })
     
      this.setState({ useremail: '' , username: '', userpassword: ''});
      this.getUsers();
      
    }
```

Comment: Lo que pretendes hacer, no es del todo correcto, y la razón es simple: estás consultando 2 veces para saber si una entidad no existe, lo cual aparte de ser ineficiente, no es del todo seguro, ya que entre cada petición otro usuario puede hacer el registro y no te enterarías de que eso ha ocurrido. La validación de unicidad de los datos la debes hacer en el backend, no en el frontend. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Te adjunto un poco de código de lo que tengo yo como registro con Node.

Aquí te dejo el modelo:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('mongoose-type-email');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Forero = new Schema({
    username: {type: String, unique: true, required: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    email: {type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.Email, required: true, unique: true},
});

module.exports =  mongoose.model('forero', Forero);
```

Y aquí el método post

```
router.post("/new", (req, res, next) => {
  // Aquí puedes tomar los datos que quieras mandar, yo mandaba usuario, contraseña y el 
    email
  var { username, password, email } = req.body;
  // Aquí eliminaba espacios por delante y por detrás del texto para evitar problemas
  username = username.trim();
  password = password.trim();
  email = email.trim();
  try {
    // Aquí creaba el forero, que en el modelo está definido como un username unico.
    var foreroUser = new forero({
      username: username,
      password: password,
      email: email,
    });
    // Si devuelve error, es que el usuarui ya está en uso
    foreroUser.save((err, doc) => {
      if (err) {
        res
          .status(400)
          .send({
            error: "El usuario y/o el email ya están en uso por otro forero",
          });
      } else {
        res.status(200).send({ username: doc.username });
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error", error);
    res
      .status(400)
      .send({
        error: "Se ha producido un error. Inténtelo de nuevo en otro momento",
      });
  }
});
```

Comment: ok esa validacion en el backend la tengo el email y el username son unicos el problema me da que cuando el frond recive el status en este caso le pongo 302 por que ya hay uno el no detecta el state osea que no muestra el msj usario ya en uso si no que tira error por consola state.302 que es el que  le asigne

Comment: este es el codigo del front

Comment: if(res.status === 301){
            alert.show('Usuario Existente');
            }
            if(res.status === 302){
                alert.show('Emaild alredy exist.');
            }
            
            else {

                await axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/users', {
                useremail: this.state.useremail,
                username: this.state.username,
                userpassword: this.state.userpassword
  
                })
            }

Comment: no se que es lo que hago mal

Comment: y este es el cogigo en el back

Comment: const user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username});
      if (user) {
        return res.status(303).json({ msg: "The username already Exist" });
      } 
      const email = await User.findOne({useremail: req.body.useremail})
      if (email) {
          return res.status(303).json({ msg: "the email alredy exist."});
      }
      
      if(res.status === 303){
        show.alert(res.body.msg)
        }

      
     
      const newUser = new User(req.body);
      await newUser.save();
      return res.status(201).json(newUser);

Comment: el problema es que si la peticion la hago por insomia me tira bien los msj osea el codigo esxiste pero cuando la hago popr el front en cosola me dice que recive el status302 pero no aparece el msj en pantalla de usurio ya existe

Comment: La verdad, creo que el problema viene en user, cuando haces una query no puedes setearla como una propiedad (como has hecho ahí con el conts user = await User.findOne), ya que eso siempre devuelve undefined. Lo que debes hacer es un 
`User.findOne({username: req.body.username})
.then((doc, err) => {console.log(doc)});`

De esta forma obtienes si el usuario existe o no.

Comment: `UserModel.findOne({username: username}, (err, person) => {
    if(person) {
      return res.sendStatus(250);
    } else {
      var salt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999) + Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999);
      var cryptr = new Cryptr(salt.toString());
      var encryptedPassword = cryptr.encrypt(password);
      let person = new UserModel({
        name: name,
        surname: surname,
        username: username,
        password: encryptedPassword,
        salt: salt
      });
      person.save();
      return res.send(person.id);
    }`